# R: How Plot an Excel Table(Matrix) with R

Tags: r, excel, matrix, draw, curve

I got this problem I still haven't found out how to solve it. I want to plot all the Values `MW1`, `MW2` and `MW3` in function of "DHT + Procymidone". How can I plot all this values in the graphic so that I will get 3 different curves (in different colors and different number like curve 1, 2, ...)? And I want the labels of the X-Values("DHT + Procymidone") to be like -10, -9, ... , -4 instead of 1,00E-10, ...

```
DHT + Procymidone   MW 1                MW 2                MW 3
1,00E-10            114,259526780335    111,022461066274    213,212408408682
1,00E-09            115,024187788314    111,083316791613    114,529425136628
1,00E-08            110,517449986348    107,867941606743    125,10230718665
1,00E-07            100,961311263444    98,4219995773135    116,045168653416
1,00E-06            71,2383604211297    73,539659636842     50,3213799775309
1,00E-05            20,3553333652104    36,1345771905088    15,42260866106
1,00E-04            4,06189509055904    18,1246447874679    10,1988107887318
```

Answer (score 0):

I have shortened your data frame for convenience reasons, so here's an example:

```
mydat <- data.frame(DHT_Procymidone = c(-10, -9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4),
                    MW1 = c(114, 115, 110, 100, 72, 20, 4),
                    MW2 = c(111, 111, 107, 98, 73, 36, 18),
                    MW3 = c(213, 114, 123, 116, 50, 15, 10))

library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
mydf <- gather(mydat, "grp", "MW", 2:4)

ggplot(mydf, aes(x = DHT_Procymidone, y = MW, colour = grp)) + geom_line()
```

which gives following plot:

[image]

To use ggplot, your data needs to be in long-format. `gather` does this for you, appending columns MW1-MW3 into one column, while the column names are added as new column values in the `grp`-column. This group-column allows to identify different groups, i.e. different colored lines in the plot.

Depending on the type of `DHT + Procymidone`, you can, e.g. use `format(..., scientific = FALSE)` to convert to numeric, however, this will result in -0.0000000001 (and not -10).

However, if this data column is a character vector (you can coerce with `as.character`), this may work:

```
a <- "1,00E-10"
sub("1,00E", "", a, fixed = TRUE)

> [1] "-10"
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative answer to @Daniel's which doesn't rely on ggplot (thanks Daniel for providing the reproducible data).

```
mydat <- data.frame(DHT_Procymidone = c(-10, -9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4),
                    MW1 = c(114, 115, 110, 100, 72, 20, 4),
                    MW2 = c(111, 111, 107, 98, 73, 36, 18),
                    MW3 = c(213, 114, 123, 116, 50, 15, 10))

plot(mydat[,2] ~ mydat[,1], typ = "l", ylim = c(0,220), xlim = c(-10,-2), xlab = "DHT Procymidone", ylab = "MW")
lines(mydat[,3] ~ mydat[,1], col = "blue")
lines(mydat[,4] ~ mydat[,1], col = "red")
legend(x = -4, y = 200, legend = c("MW1","MW2","MW3"), lty = 1, bty = "n", col = c("black","blue","red"))
```

To change axis labels see the text in `xlab` and `ylab`. To change axis limits see `xlim` and `ylim`.